# Mongodb atlas search: which analyzer is the best for searching multiple terms with AND condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I'm trying to build MongoDB Atlas full text search index. However, I'm struggle a bit with the analyzers.

Here is my index:

```
{
  "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
  "searchAnalyzer": "lucene.standard",
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "description": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is when I perform the search over the "description" field.

This is the way how I perform the search:

```
{
  index: 'description_index',
  text: {
    query: 'chicken alfredo',
    path: 'description'
  }
}
```

This returns documents where in description field there is either "chicken" or "alfredo" or both. But I need it to return document(s) where in description field there are both "chicken" and "alfredo". Note that, the string in description field could contain other words, for example "Roasted Chicken Alfredo with Chips". In this example my desired solution should return "Roasted Chicken Alfredo with Chips" document but not the document with the following description "Chicken Roberto".

Any ideas how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think the analyzer needs to change. I've added a query alternative that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying using the [phrase](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/phrase/) operator, which would change your query to this:

```js
{
   index: 'description_index',
   phrase: {
     query: 'chicken alfredo',
     path: 'description'
   }
 }
```

Comment: If I use "phrase" operator instead of "text" operator then speed will not be an issue right? I want to have very performant query

Comment: thanks a lot. I've tested it and it's exactly what I need to have

Comment: phrase will be faster and computationally less expensive than regular expression but i think it's helpful to have the context.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up the solution. However, the one suggested by @Nice-Guy is better and cleaner.

Here is mine:

```
{
  index: 'description_index',
  regex: {
    query: '.*chicken alfredo.*',
    path: 'description'
  }
}
```

This query ideally requires **lucene.keyword** analyzer instead of **lucene.standard** and also the query is case sensitive.

Comment: It's very slow. Do you know if it's possible to achieve it where query is more performant?

Comment: @Matt Yep, it's very slow. That's why you have to use the solution provided by Nice-Guy